# Взаимодействие между service и activity

Tags: android-service

Есть такая конструкция myService.java:

```
public class myService extends Service{
public void onCreate(){
...
}
public void add(...){
...
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){ 
return null;
}
}
```

Как мне при старте сервиса использовать метод add(...)? Я не знаю как правильно это сделать, я искал но не нашел ответы.
Пришло в голову сделать так(в MainAсtivity.java), но очевидно ничего не работало и приложение вылетало:

```
myService service = new myService();
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.getClass()));
service.add(...);
```

Как сделать что-то типа на примере выше?

P.s service в AndroidManifest.xml прописан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не делается. Вам нужно сделать *binding (привязку)* сервиса к `Activity`, тогда вы будете иметь ссылку на `Service`.

Документация [Service Binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)